# Set the background image Onclick of a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to set the backgound image of div1 to be the image that has been clicked.

```js
function change(){
  
  document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage ='url(' + this.src + ')';
};
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
 <div id="div2">
 <div id="div3" ><img src="myurl" id="image" onclick="change();"/></div>
</div>
```

The above Js function isn't doing it.

Comment: It's working for me, the background for `#div1` is changed to `background-image: url(http://stacksnippets.net/undefined);`

Comment: I guess script function will not understand `this`. Try again by changing these lines
`onclick = "change(this)"`

`function change(this){`

Comment: @psylogic : checkout the answer i have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the html onclick function call to pass `this` as a parameter to the function and change the JS code to the following

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
 <div id="div2">
 <div id="div3" ><img src="myurl" id="image" onclick="change(this);"/></div>
</div>
```

```
function change(img){
var urlString = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage =urlString;
};
```

Comment: I was going to suggest sending the id to change(), but sending this is cleaner.

Comment: but i couldn't see the image. Could you?

Answer (score -1):

Add dimensions to your div (width and Height) to see changes.

```js
function change(src){
  
  document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage ='url(' + src + ')';
};
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
 <div id="div2">
 <div id="div3" ><img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" id="image" onclick="change(this.src);"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following by passing `this` into change.  You can then correctly reference the image url.

```js
function change(img){
  document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage ='url(' + img.src + ')';
};
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
 <div id="div2">
 <div id="div3"><img src="myurl" id="image" onclick="change(this);"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've tried this in firefox and I dont know why  it doesn't work :(